# How to modify .TXT ParseFile

Tags: php, parse-platform

Reading up on [the official PHP documentation on ParseFiles](https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#files), there is only help for creating and retrieving ParseFiles. I'm attempting to create a message log .txt file to be stored in Parse. When a user submits a message, I need to append it on said .txt file for other users to be able to read it. But on the ParseFile PHP class there are only creation and deletion functions, no modification functions.

The way I'm approaching this so far is as follows (might be pseudo code):

```
$f = fopen($parseFile->getURL(), 'a');
fwrite($f, "Some text\n");
$newF = ParseFile::createFromFile($f, "Some name");
$newF->save();
$parseObj->set("content", $newF);
```

But this seems unnecessary and inefficient. ParseFile also has a `getData()` function which downloads the file as an array (each line as an element? It's not specified), but again there is no function to save the new content, I have to create a new ParseFile with the new data, save it, and set it to the ParseObject.

I would like to either use a built-in function to edit the ParseFile and re-save it, or have a more efficient way of appending content to the file rather than fetching the full file and re-saving it with little extra content, especially since users could send many messages.

Thanks!

Comment: You really should use their "database" instead of thinking text files. I don't see any reason at all to use a file instead?

Comment: @hank I wanted to have each conversation in a single object, but objects have a limited size of 128k so I couldn't just dump the conversation as a string there. ParseFiles have a size limit of 10M, so I could store a lot more. Regardless, from the other answer it looks like this wasn't the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse has file storage but it isn't a first person offering, you don't get a file system or direct query to files. What you're trying to do should not be done using files. Your current code is littering the data store with lots of growing copies of the same file throughout its history.

If you continue to use parse then you should use objects to record your messages. The messages should include a time stamp so you can fetch the appropriate content in a suitable order. If you need all messages you would paginate through the query.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier. I wanted to avoid creating lots of objects for messages but it seems it's the right way to do it (or at least it's better than my idea), it's been implemented this way now. Thanks for your input.